# Can I get validation rule of custom object using eclipse salesforce IDE

Tags: ide, eclipse

I am using `Version: Juno Service Release 2` and salesforce plugin and I made a local copy of my sandbox but am unable to find the validation rules in my eclipse copy. any suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

You can find validation rules in the .object file for the custom object in question, look for `<validationRules>`.  You'll need to make sure that the custom object is selected in the "Add/Remove Metadata Components...." dialog in Eclipse.  You can find documentation for all of the metadata files, including .object files, in the [Metadata API Guide](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_meta/).  In particular, here is the [documentation on validationRules](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_meta/Content/meta_validationformulas.htm)